# Можно ли в одной строчке создать массив, а в другой его проинициализировать?

Tags: java, массивы, конструктор

Можно ли в одной строчке создать массив, а в другой его проинициализировать полностью, например:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array;
        array = {"text1", "text2", "text3"};
    }
}
```

чтобы было то же самое, что и

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = {"text1", "text2", "text3"};
    }
}
```

Comment: нет, конкретно **так** нельзя. но проинициализовать *по-другому* - можно

Comment: Если вам неизвестен конкретный размер массива - то проще использовать список

Comment: Што? Как нельзя? ```String[] array;
        array = new String[]{"text1", "text2", "text3"};```

Comment: @lampa `Што? Как нельзя?` а теперь сравните, как написал автор и как 
 вы. Как автор написал - нельзя. А вы написали *по-другому*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, но для этого нужно явно создать объект массива:

```
String[] array;
array = new String[] {"text1", "text2", "text3"};
```

В первой строке *объявляется* переменная `array`. Во второй *создается* массив, который присваивается переменной.

Без `new String[]` не получится т.к. использование инициализатора `{"text1", "text2", "text3"}` ограничено спецификацией. Разрешенные сценарии предполагают, что вместе с инициализатором будет явно указан тип.

В спецификации ([JLS §10.6 Array Initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)) сказано, что инициализатор может быть указан либо в объявлении полей/переменных, либо как часть выражения создания массива:

> An array initializer may be specified in a field declaration ([§8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3), [§9.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3)) or local variable declaration ([§14.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4)), or as part of an array creation expression ([§15.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1)), to create an array and provide some initial values.
>
> ***§10.6. Инициализаторы массивов.***
>    Инициализатор массива может быть указан в объявлении поля ([§8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3), [§9.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3)) или локальной переменной ([§14.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4)) или как часть выражения создания массива для создания массива ([§15.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1)) и представления некоторых его исходных значений.

Выражение создание массива всегда начинается с `new` ([15.10.1. Array Creation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1)):

> ```
> ArrayCreationExpression:  
>     new PrimitiveType DimExprs [Dims] 
>     new ClassOrInterfaceType DimExprs [Dims] 
>     new PrimitiveType Dims ArrayInitializer 
>     new ClassOrInterfaceType Dims ArrayInitializer
> ```

Соответственно, без `new` инициализатор получится использовать только при объявлении переменных.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] array = new String[3];// создать массив из 3 строк со значениями null

array[0] = "some string 1"; // записать в строку 0 массива некоторое 
          значение строки
array[1] = "some string 2";
array[2] = "some string 3";
```

Можете заполнить массив через цикл.

Answer (score 0):

Можно свой метод создать, без приведения типов:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr;
    arr = createArray("text1", "text2", "text3");
}

public static <T> T[] createArray(T... arr) {
    return arr;
}
```

Можно воспользоваться существующими методами, с приведением типов:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr;
    arr = Arrays.asList("text1", "text2", "text3").toArray(String[]::new);
}
```